# Woocommerce Continue Shopping Button Link to Last Product Category Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hyperlink

There are forum topics regarding custom continue shopping buttons, but there is nothing on how to link the custom button to the last product category page viewed. There is a plugin that gives the option for this; however, there is a flaw in that when the cart is refreshed, the button disappears. The following code works to create a custom message/button; however, I cannot figure out how to change the link from the shop page to the last product category page viewed:

```
/* Add Continue Shopping Button on Cart Page & Checkout page*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table', 
'woo_add_continue_shopping_button_to_cart' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 
'woo_add_continue_shopping_button_to_cart' );

function woo_add_continue_shopping_button_to_cart() {
$shop_page_url = "get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) )";

echo '<div class="woocommerce-message">';
echo ' <a href="'.$shop_page_url.'" class="button wc-forwards">Continue 
Shopping →</a> Would you like some more prints?';
echo '</div>';
}
```

Thank you in advance!
J.

Here is the code that the plugin uses to link (I think):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'hpy_cs_output_notice', 1 );
function hpy_cs_output_notice() {

$display_empty = get_option( 'hpy_cs_empty_cart_notice' );

if ( $display_empty == 'yes' ) {
    $link = wc_custom_redirect_continue_shopping();

    $message = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', 
esc_url($link), esc_html__('Continue shopping', 'woocommerce'), 
esc_html(get_option('hpy_cs_empty_cart_text', __('Your cart is empty.', '    
$message = sprintf( \'<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s\', 
esc_url( $link ), esc_html__( \'Continue shopping\', \'woocommerce\' ), 
esc_html( get_option( \'hpy_cs_empty_cart_text\', __( \'Your cart is 
empty.\', \'hpy_cshpy_cshpy_cs\' ) ) ) );
'))));

    wc_print_notice($message);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function to retrieve last category page viewed. But, I have some ideas on how this could be solved.

First is to create a custom action, check if page is category page, and set category ID to session data if so. Then on your button, use this to get proper URL.

```
/* Set up session */
add_action( 'init', 'wp_check_for_product_cat_sess');
function wp_check_for_product_cat_sess(){
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

/* Set session variable when on Category or Product page */
add_action( 'wp', 'wp_check_for_product_cat');
function wp_check_for_product_cat(){
        global $wp_query;
        if( is_product_category() ){ // This is Category; use my ID
                $_SESSION['wp_last_cat'] = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
        }
        if( is_product() ){ // This is Product; use my ID to get my Categories
                $cats = get_the_terms( $wp_query->get_queried_object(), 'product_cat' ) ;
                if( count( $cats ) > 0 ){
                        foreach($cats as $one_cat ){
                                $_SESSION['wp_last_cat'] = $one_cat->term_id;
                        }
                }
        }

        if( is_cart() ){
                // Here we output only on Cart page, as debug tool */
                var_dump( $_SESSION['wp_last_cat'] );
        }
}
```

Then you replace in your action code:

```
$shop_page_url = "get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) )";
```

Should become:

```
if( isset( $_SESSION['wp_last_cat'] ) ){
    $shop_page_url = get_term_link( $_SESSION['wp_last_cat'], 'product_cat' );
} else {
    $shop_page_url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
}
```

Second is to retrieve last item added to cart, and use that item to retrieve its category URL.

Comment: Hi Patrick! Thank you for your reply. I don't think I understand what you mean. The plugin that gives the ability to link to the last category page views uses the following code to do it (I think). Maybe there is a way to use the above code in conjunction with it to work for both creating the button and adding the correct link? (I'll edit my question with the other code)

Comment: I added in your code and replaced the action code. Is there anything else I need to do before and after? I don't understand that part. I've tried it with that code, and it behaves the same way..the link directs to the shop page.