# Add custom button with link to main category inside "added to cart" message on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

How to **add a custom button with link to main category inside "added to cart" message** on single product page of the currect product.

For clarity of the position of the custom button, see image:

[image]

---

I know how to add button with link to main shop page.

```php
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_message' );
function my_custom_add_to_cart_message( $message ) {
    $message .= sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward back-to-shop" style="margin-right: 15px;">%s</a>', get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ), 'Continue');
    return $message;
}
```

---

But i don't know how to make a link to last or main product category.

Using [Woocommerce Continue Shopping Button Link to Last Product Category Page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51333078/11987538%5D) answer code does not work for me as it is not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a button with a link to the main category, inside the "Product added to cart message" on the single product page you can use:

```php
function filter_wc_add_to_cart_message ( $message, $product_id ) {
    // Retrieves the terms for a post
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'include_children' => false ) );

    // First main product category
    $term = reset( $terms );

    // Link
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
    
    // Button
    $term_button = '<a href="' . $term_link . '" class="button">My button</a>'; 
    
    return $message . $term_button;
}
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'filter_wc_add_to_cart_message', 10, 2 );
```

---

Note: Custom CSS and minor html changes may be required, theme dependent